# Read data from csv file using java in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

How to read data of each cell in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

I have tried with following code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:/data1.csv"));
expectedLabels = reader.readNext();
FieldNames = reader.readNext();
FieldValues = reader.readNext();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File file = new File("D:/data.csv");
if(file.exists()){
 System.out.println("File Exists");
}
BufferedReader bufRdr;
bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;

while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
    col=0;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        //Following stroing the data of csv
    numbers[row][col] = st.nextToken();
    col++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    row++;
    }
    bufRdr.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

reading csv files become very easy with OPENCSV jar file. I have used this jar file couple of time to read file.

1. We have predefined class called CSVReader, create an object and pass the csv file path
2. call readAll() method which will return the csv content in List
3. using Iterator, you can iterate all the values and use according to application

I have written article on this have a look it might help you.

http://learn-automation.com/how-to-read-csv-files-using-java/

Comment: Is it possible to paste the relevant code from the article here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to provider string type variable in `FileReader()` function , it shows error while passing `filereader()` method with parameter in buffer reader fn

code shown below:

```
String f1= (System.getProperty("User.dir") + "\\Module9TestNG\\src\\TestLogin.xlsx");       
BufferedReader bufRdr;
bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String record; 
String url= null;

while ((record = bufRdr.readLine()) != null)
{
     String fields[] = record.split(",");
     url= fields[0].toString();
}
```

Comment: String f1= (System.getProperty("User.dir") + "\\Module9TestNG\\src\\TestLogin.xlsx");  
 BufferedReader bufRdr;
 bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   String record; 
   String url= null;
 
   while ((record = bufRdr.readLine()) != null)
       {
           String fields[] = record.split(",");
           url= fields[0].toString();
           
       }

Answer (score 0):

```
   private String Fpath ="D:\\CkycApps.csv";   
    String line;
    File file = new File(Fpath);

    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);       
        String[] cell= line.split(",");
            String FirstName=cell[0];
            String MiddleName=cell[1];
```

}

Comment: Please add some explanation